# How can I use AllowOverride in nginx?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, laravel

I'm testing a website that was made on apache with lavavel in php. I'm setting it up on nginx now but I'm getting 500 errors on all the subpages, I was told to use `AllowOverride` but I dont know how to use it on nginx.

Comment: See the Laravel [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements) last section you will find the configuration for nginx.

Answer (score 5):

There is no alternative for `AllowOverride` in nginx.

Also, make sure you have installed the  PHP handler `php5-fpm` in order to process PHP scripts.